# Visualforce Page requested twice in Desktop Lightning mode (and in no other view/mode)

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I have a strange problem in Salesforce. I have a Visualforce Page shown in the Account page that works correctly in Classic Salesforce and also in the Salesforce 1 Lightning view as seen on an iPad. However in the Lightning desktop mode the Visualforce Page is requested twice when loading the Account page:

The request is something like:

GET `/apex/accountPanel?id={idhere}&isdtp=p1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=https://eu6.lightning.force.com&sfdcIFrameHost=web`

This returns the Visualforce Page details as HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html><head>
... etc ...
</html>
```

The request occurring twice breaks the Visualforce Page (as it is showing an iframe which hits our site and performs various operations.) The Visualforce Page is only shown on the screen once (and would look fine if the 2 requests didn't interfere with the logic of the site - which I could probably fix but thought the 2 requests from Salesforce looked wrong.)

The second request is only seen in the Desktop Lightning mode. Any ideas anyone?

TIA.

**Update**

I've looked into this further and to rule out any odd behaviours coming from my particular Visualforce page I have created a brand new Visualforce page with limited functionality:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
  <h1>Test</h1>
  Hello World
</apex:page>
```

Adding this to the Account page and viewing the Account page in Desktop Lightning mode does the above behaviour of retrieving the Visualforce page twice (proving this is a general Visualforce issue):

/apex/New_VF_page?id{id}&isdtp=p1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=https://eu6.lightning.force.com&sfdcIFrameHost=web

and

/apex/New_VF_page?id={id}&isdtp=p1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=https://eu6.lightning.force.com&sfdcIFrameHost=web

This returns the HTML of the Visualforce page as before.

Comment: Have you gone through the Trailhead [Visualforce & Lightning Pages Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules)? I suggest you take a look at this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that helps - the problem is that the Visual force page is requested twice by Salesforce

Comment: Did you look at earlier in that module about the wrapper that Lightning puts around VF when it places it in it's Iframe which is served from a different server than your VF page is and can affect CORS? Are you calling any JS for example that tries to set the Window location? There are a lot of potential issues that you need to be aware of if calling accessing session Ids, and other things. I suggest you post your page code if none of these apply.

Comment: Thanks. It isn't a CORS issue as the Visual Force page is literally retrieved twice (the wrapping it does, happens twice). I removed the logic from the Visual Force page (so it just showed a hello message and included some JS) and Salesforce still requested the control twice.

Comment: Again, I recommend you read the entire module I referred you to. There's far more than I can possibly convey here. You also mention "site" which could mean this is happening in a Community or Sites page. VF is served from a different server than lightning is and much is still unknown. You may need to file a case on this.